# Vuetify don't override all sass variables

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I'm trying to configure my vuetify theme by overriding the sass variables.

But I'm a bit confused because some variables overrides perfectly the theme and while others no.

**For example this works:**

```
$body-font-family: 'Poppins';
$font-size-root: 14px;

$headings: (
  'h1': (
    'size': 24px,
    'line-height': 1.15em
  ),
  'h2': (
    'size': 18px,
    'line-height': 1.5em
  )
);
```

**But this doesn't works :**

```
$border-radius-root: 40px;

$btn-letter-spacing: 5px;
$btn-font-weight: 700;
```

**Here is my entry point :**

```
@import 'theme/map.scss';

@import '~vuetify/src/styles/main.sass';
```

**My vuetify instanciation :**

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

const theme = require('../theme')

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  iconfont: 'fa',
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: theme.colors.primary.base,
        'primary-dark': theme.colors.primary.dark,
        'primary-light': theme.colors.primary.light,

        secondary: theme.colors.secondary.base,
        'secondary-dark': theme.colors.secondary.dark,
        'secondary-light': theme.colors.secondary.light,

        content: theme.colors.content.base,
        'content-dark': theme.colors.content.dark,
        'content-light': theme.colors.content.light,

        danger: theme.colors.danger.base,
        'danger-dark': theme.colors.danger.dark,
        'danger-light': theme.colors.danger.light,

        success: theme.colors.success.base,
        'success-dark': theme.colors.success.dark,
        'success-light': theme.colors.success.light,

        accent: theme.colors.accent
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**And my vue.config.js :**

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `@import "@/assets/styles/theme/map.scss";`
      }
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify']
}
```

My version of vuetify is 2.2.11 and 1.3 for vuetify-loader.

I really don't understand why some vars doesn't work and it would be really cool if someone here could help me.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: So `theme/map.scss` contains the overriding variables?

Comment: @YomS.
Yes it look like that :
```@import 'global/map.scss';
@import 'components/map.scss';```
And the ```map.scss``` file brings back to the overriding variables

Comment: If these overriding variables are really contained inside `map.scss` then it should work, given that you have added it with `prependData`; otherwise, you're gonna have to prepend the right file(s).

Comment: @YomS
And m’y problem is here, thé overriding works with variables like ´´´ $body-font-family’´´ or ´´´ $font-size-root:´´´ but not width others like ´´´$border-radius-root’´´ and I dont know why